# QSerialport is blocked in QThread

Tags: multithreading, qt, serial-port, qthread

I was trying to read the serial output from a thread. The Serial port is opened in main program and passed the QSerialPort variable to thread. The thread is called using signals and slot mechanism like following code.

```
connect(m_serial, &QSerialPort::readyRead, this, &MySerialPort::startReadingThread);
```

Then I called serial.readAll() function in thread and print the received data into logs. But after some time the serialport get blocked and not printing any data.

```
 QByteArray message = MySerialPort::m_serial->readAll();
 qDebug() << message;
```

Can anyone tell me why the serialport get blocked.

Comment: Does it work single-threaded? Also, why do you need the thread anyway?

Comment: Did you you change the thread affinity of `m_serial` using `m_serial->moveToThread(new_thread)`?  If not then you probably have a direct connection executing between code on different threads resulting in undefined behaviour.  Impossible to say more without a [mcve].  As pointed out by @hyde , however, there really shouldn't be any need to use a separate thread for this.

Comment: I am reading the mavlink messages from serialport and update their values on QML UI. Its all run in single thread. The mavlink messages are comming so fast, due to this the the values are not updated in UI so fastly. Thats why I am using seperate threads i.e the reading from serial port in one thread and updating UI in other thread.

Comment: LOL, how many people will know what "mavlink" is? OK I happen to be one of them.... :)  Yea it's potentially a flood of data, and just a `qDebug()` of that can easily grind an app to a halt (esp. a GUI one).  But as others have stated, you'll need to provide a lot more of a MRE... and ultimately you'll need to learn how to properly buffer all that data if needed. If you're just shuttling data directly to a file then maybe it will be easier. But if you're parsing the data in between.... you'll likely need a buffer. You also don't state what _else_ the app is doing at the time, if anything.

Comment: Also from the scant example given you appear to be reading the data from the main thread, so it's not multi-threaded really.

Comment: Note that `readAll` will block until the there is nothing left to read. I am not sure what this means for serial ports, maybe you have to close the device to get any result. Anyway try some other read function and see if that works.

Comment: @Steak Nah don't need to close the serial port to return from `readAll()` (`QIODevice` stuff typically works as expected). But what the OP is referring to is a constant stream of telemetry data, possibly over an wireless/lossy link, and possibly quite a lot of it (depending on many factors). So it's not unlikely that there is always data to read. And of course you're correct that it would block.